# Compare two Columns with different length

Tags: pyspark

I'm working with two PySpark Dataframes, each one have one column. One with 3 rows(ColumnA), and the other with 100 rows(ColumnB).
I want to compare **all rows** of ColumnA with **every single row** of ColumnB. (I need to known if any of the dates in ColumnA is bigger than the one in ColumnB, if so add in ColumnX a 1)

[image]

Comment: Please show what you have already tried

Answer (score 1):

**Cross Join** is a solution -

For example -

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *      
from pyspark.sql.functions import *  

A = [11, 2, 13, 4]
B = [5, 6]

df = spark.createDataFrame(A,IntegerType())
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(B,IntegerType())
df.select(col("value").alias("A")).crossJoin(df1.select(col("value").alias("B"))).withColumn("C",when(col("A") > col("B"),1).otherwise(0)).select("A","B","C").show()

+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|
+---+---+---+
| 11|  5|  1|
| 11|  6|  1|
|  2|  5|  0|
|  2|  6|  0|
| 13|  5|  1|
| 13|  6|  1|
|  4|  5|  0|
|  4|  6|  0|
+---+---+---+
```